# Widget type radio buttons and N/A

Tags: entities

I have a field so-called "Status" in my custome contact type. It is a List (integer) and widget type is "Radio buttons". I added two values for allowed values list:

```
 0|Sold
 1|Available
```

Default value is "Available". But Drupal lists this as below:

```
 () N/A
 () Sold
 () Available
```

Why does Drupal add this unnecessary "N/A" to the radio buttons? I encountered this problem since D6. Now, I'm using the latest version 7.14. I'm still seeing this.

I know I can remove the "N/A" by writing a hook from a custom module.
Nonetheless, I don't want to write additional codes for this kind of small thing. When I use "Select list", it is ok with an option "-None-", but the radio button is ideally suited for the two options.

How can I remove it without installing additional module? Am I missing some functionalities from Drupal core interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When your field is required, no `N/A` options should show up** (and you said you need this field to be required).
To show you an example,

1. [I created a new content type named "First test content type"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kjjk.png) (with the machine name `first_test_content_type`)
2. Went to *"Manage fields"*, and [added a field with radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDIlV.png) (with the machine name `field_test_radio_buttons`)
3. Added the mentioned options:

   ```
   0|Sold
   1|Available
   ```
4. I checked the *"Required field"* checkbox (**this is the key** for not seeing `N/A` as a separate option!!)
5. Made "Available" the default option
6. So, on `/admin/structure/types/manage/first-test-content-type/fields/field_test_radio_buttons`, the following shows up: [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVU76.png)
7. When [adding a new "First test content type" content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8olyo.png), I can see the following radio buttons (click on the image to see the whole page):
   [image: Test radio buttons]
8. So [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHBnz.png).

Comment: I overlooked this because I see the N/A in the field configuration page.

Comment: @SithuKyaw: ah, I see, yes, it really shows up when [editing the field settings](http://i.imgur.com/44ZTS.png), but when selecting another value as default, it won't show up on the user interface. Anyway, I'm glad your problem is solved!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should help.

```
(function($) {
  $('.form-radio[value=_none]').parent().hide();
})(jQuery);
```

http://drupal.org/node/1623360

Answer (score 2):

If your field is not required and not multiple then there's no way to remove the *N/A* without writing some custom code I'm afraid.

It's hard-coded into the [`_options_properties()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!options!options.module/function/_options_properties/7) function:

```
// Add a 'none' option for non-required radio buttons.
if (!$required && !$multiple) {
  $properties['empty_option'] = 'option_none';
}
```

Your only choice is to write a small form alter hook unfortunately; this was obviously a design decision made by the core developers when they were implementing that module's functionality. I'd imagine the justification would be UX-based but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think Drupal should hide or show it upon field required or optional. I'm expecting this feature in later core releases. Do you know where can I report this?

Comment: I think the [core issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal) would be the best place to start

Answer (score 1):

It's implemented that way, because otherwise users don't have any way to deselect a radio button, and for some (government) sites that's a requirement.

To change it use:

- a form_alter in a custom module
- javascript inside your theme to hide the N/A option.
- [theme_options_none](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21options%21options.module/function/theme_options_none/7)

Comment: My field is required, thus the N/A is not in deed necessary. No need to deselect it. Any way, I voted you.

Comment: @SithuKyaw: wait, is your field really **required**? So is the "Required field" checked when you go to `admin/structure/types/manage/this-is-your-test-content-type/fields/field_this_is_your_field_with_radio_buttons`? Please show us a screenshot about that! In case you have "Required field" checked, the `N/A` shouldn't show up - just tested it, and I don't have any `N/A` options!

Comment: @Sk8erPeter: Thanks, you helped me! Will you post this as an answer or will I post by myself.

Comment: @SithuKyaw: you're welcome, I'm glad then. I posted a [separate answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/38898/2368) with many screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($form['fieldname'][$form['fieldname']['#language']]['#options']['_none']);
```

should do it in a form_alter hook. replace "fieldname" with your field's name. this should work for all select fields no matter what widget is used.

cheers,
j

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this "N/A" radio button option for all fields, or just specific fields, using the following [`hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/7) implemention:

```
<?php 

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function modulename_field_widget_options_buttons_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if (!isset($context['field']) || !isset($context['instance'])) {
    return;
  }
  $field = $context['field'];
  $field_instance = $context['instance'];

  if (!isset($field['field_name']) || !isset($field_instance['entity_type'])) {
    return;
  }
  $field_name = $field['field_name'];
  $entity_type = $field_instance['entity_type'];

  if (isset($element['#type'])
      && $element['#type'] === 'radios'
      && isset($element['#options'])
      && is_array($element['#options'])
  ) {
    $options =& $element['#options'];
    unset($options['_none']);
  }
}

?>
```

To limit this to change only selected fields, check on the `$field_name` and `$entity_type`.

Answer (score -1):

One of the interesting Features of Drupal 7 is the Field API. Prior to Drupal 6, to make a custom field the Core Profile Module and Content Profile Modules are used. Now in Drupal 7 we can make any custom field to appear in User Registration Form. When Adding Custom Fields Such as Gender usually we use Radio Button Input. However there is a small Problem with the core module as it displays the third option N/A in the input. To Remove the N/A option the field needs to be set as mandatory. To Remove this option there is another way. Go to modules/field/modules/options/options.module and comment the the code $properties['empty_option'] = ‘option_none’ as shown below under buttons.

```
case ‘buttons’:
$properties = array(
‘filter_xss’ => TRUE,
);
// Add a ‘none’ option for non-required radio buttons.
if (!$required && !$multiple) {
//$properties['empty_option'] = ‘option_none’; 
}
break;

case ‘onoff’:
$properties = array(
‘filter_xss’ => TRUE,
);
break;
}
```

However the proper way to achieve it would be to override this function in custom module. But for a quick fix we can also follow this method. [blog]: http://yamafm.wordpress.com/ "click here for updates"